# How to get project path deployed in tomcat using Java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, path

Here is my project path deployed in TOMCAT--
D:\PMT\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\MyProject

How can it get the absolute path which my project is deployed in tomcat

I use **`System.getProperty("catalina.home")`** but it only return :

```
D:\PMT\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\
```

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

Use [ServletContext.getRealPath(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

From the Servlet documentation

> Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path.
>
> For example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return
>   the absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request
>   of the form http://://index.html would be
>   mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this
>   ServletContext.
>
> The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer
>   and operating system on which the servlet container is running,
>   including the proper path separators.

Comment: getRealPath is static method?? i cannot use this method@@

Comment: No, it is a method of the ServletContext object. You have access to the ServletContext everywhere. From within a Servlet, a call to getServletContext() returns the context where getServletContext() is a method of the super class GenericServlet

Answer (score 0):

Using the system property **catalina.base** is much better because Tomcat's start script **catalina.sh** will set this property. So this will work as long as you don't try to run your app on a different server.

```
File catalinaBase = new File( System.getProperty( "catalina.base" ) ).getAbsoluteFile();
File propertyFile = new File( catalinaBase, "webapps/strsproperties/strs.properties" );

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream( propertyFile );
```